# Good fractal visualizer

Tags: visualization

*Each time it's the same thing, I find one, then I forget the name of it the next time I want to "dive" into such things.*

I'm looking for a good fractal "visualizer". The kind in which you just select a well-known fractal model (or variations on it), and in which you can then "dive" into, just zooming in or out smoothly, for the sheer pleasure of losing yourself in it.

I'm looking for an executable, preferably for Windows, but any OS accepted. Keep to one program per answer (and one answer per program), as this is community wiki.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lately I've been using [GNU XaoS](http://wmi.math.u-szeged.hu/xaos/doku.php) under Ubuntu.  It runs on Windows, OS X, Linux and Unix-like systems.

[image]

Comment: That's the one I always forget the name of! Thank you.

Comment: @gnoupi: i always remember it cause some cultures use "x" to represent a "k" sound.  so this would be pronounced "Chaos" -- as in chaos mathematics.

Comment: hmm, didn't know that, nice.

Comment: It it not k, but IPA /x/, like in English "loch". It comes from a greek letter χ (chi), which looks like x. In, for instance, Polish /x/ is written as ch, and in Polish chaos is written chaos, and read /xaos/, close to the ancient Greek original.

Answer (score 5):

For old skool try [Fractint](http://spanky.triumf.ca/www/FRACTint/fractint.html) in [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/)

[image: Mandelbrot]

[image: Julia]

Comment: there's a linux/X port too: [xfractint](http://spanky.triumf.ca/www/fractint/xfractint_port.html), available in the debian repositories or those of your favorite package manager.

Comment: +1 Fractint... that takes me back! (wipes wistful tear from eye!)